# In Visual Studio, how do I debug a project without building it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This is for Visual Studio 2008.

I have `Tools|Projects and Solutions|Build and Run|On Run, when projects are out of date` set to `Always build` because that is what I usually want.  However, there are some times (when I am examining historic versions in version control) where I want to skip the build process.  Is there a magic keystroke that will override the build step for exactly one debugging session so I don't have to change the setting and change it back?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Please right click solution name and go to `Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Configuration`, clear the Build checkbox of the project.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, although I am no longer in the situation where I need to do this.  (It's been a few years since I asked the question ;-).)  The steps seem reasonable and is shorter than hunting through `Tools|...`, although you have to remember to turn the build back on again.

Comment: Very useful advice for remote debugging. You may manually build the solution and then copy Debug folder to remote machine. It's rather more convenient than attaching the remote process.

Answer (score 8):

In VS2013 it is: right click `solution -> Configuration Manager`, and clear Build checkbox of your project(s).

Answer (score 7):

I found it convenient to create a new build configuration in order to do this. 
Right-click the solution in the Solution Explorer and choose `Properties`. From there, choose `Configuration Properties / Configuration`. Now choose `Configuration Manager` and create a new configuration as shown. You can create the build configuration as a copy of your Debug project:

[image]

Then, press `OK` and turn off all of the project build flags:

[image]

Visual Studio will have created a folder underneath the `bin` folder in the startup project with the name of the new configuration. Copy your pre-built files into there and run the new configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I put the following function in my `NuGet_profile.ps1`:

```bsh
function debugnobuild() {
    # temporarily disable build (same as Properties -> Configuration -> ..)
    $buildProjects = @($DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration.SolutionContexts |
    where ShouldBuild | foreach {
        $_.ShouldBuild = $false
        $_.ProjectName
    })
    try {
        # start debugging
        $DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.Debug()
    }
    finally {
        # undo changes
        $DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration.SolutionContexts |
        where { $buildProjects -contains $_.ProjectName } | foreach {
            $_.ShouldBuild = $true
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call `debugnobuild` (or any name you prefer) in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is: Set a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` line in the code, run the program seperately, attach the debugger in VS.

Comment: I don't think that would have work for me.  The point is that I have an binary and I don't want to recompile it.

Answer (score -6):

No, there isn't. You can't debug an historic version without running it, which implies building it. VS debugs against the current symbols and binary, which will be out sync with the source without building it, making debugging impossible.

Comment: I don't want to open a different can of worms, but I checked in both the compiled executable and the .pdb files (in a tag, so it's not in any branch).  So, I really do have everything I need -- I want to Visual Studio to not blow it away.

Comment: Start the program seperately, open the old codebase in VS and attach the debugger manually.

Comment: I want to debug the initialization, so I need break points in place pretty early on.

Comment: Make a VM just with VS and the codebase. Checkout the relevant code to a new folder and debug that. If you don't want to taint your current build, you'll have to do something with a bit more work, you won't get around it.