# How to get a crash dump (or any usable crash report) for a converted Windows Store UWP app?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I submitted to Windows 10 Store my `native` Win32 app that was [converted to UWP](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) app using `Project Centennial` converter. The app passed store certification and is available via a private link (while I'm testing it.)

While running my tests the app hung up and crashed once. So I was trying to retrieve any usable crash dumps to diagnose the problem.

I logged in to the [Windows Dev account](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows), then went to my `Dashboard` and sure enough the app was showing one crash:

[image]

I then clicked on it. The new `Health` page showed the time when the crash took place, market, etc. (Stuff that would not help me debug the issue.)

Then at the bottom I saw this:

[image]

I clicked the blue link where it said `MOAPPLICATION_HANG_` and it opened up `Failure details` window. Then if I scrolled all the way down (past date and time of the hit graph), I see this:

[image]

OK. Stack trace is not exactly what I was expecting, but I'll take a look.

So if I click on `stack trace`, I get this pop up:

[image]

Then if I click download I get a tiny text file `stackTrace.tsv` (117 bytes) that literally had this in it:

[image]

Is there a way to retrieve a functional [mini-dump `.dmp` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349(v=vs.85).aspx) that I can use in Visual Studio C++ project to analyze this crash with a `native` debugger?

Comment: Hey @StefanWickMSFT is there an updated way to retrieve a crash dump from Windows Store? The method I described below no long works.

Comment: The Store doesn't provide crash dump files by default (this is unrelated to Desktop-Bridge, same is true for UWP crashes). The .dmp file delivery gets enabled on a per-account basis. I would suggest you open a ticket with the Store.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: Oh, thanks, dude! I didn't know that. Why wouldn't they document that. Anyway, just a rhetorical point. I just submitted an email "incident" at [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) with a request to enable .dmp file collection for my account. It was somewhat tricky to find. I'm assuming that's what you meant, right?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: Well dude, [here's the run-around](https://i.imgur.com/SdB2IHQ.png) I got from the ticket I submitted to the Windows Store via my dev account. Nothing unusual. (That is why I stay away from any of the outsourced support lines these days.) So now what?

Comment: I followed up with the team that owns this and it turns out my info was outdated. The dump file delivery is already turned on for all developer accounts for some time now, but we are only allowed to share dump files collected in Windows Insider builds, not from production builds. So you would need to get at least once instance of your crash on an Insider build in order to see a .dmp in your dev center account.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT: Thanks for following up on that. Unfortunately for that setup, if I'm running an insider build I will also set up WER to collect all crash dumps for me. What matters are those crashes in production environment that slipped through the cracks. I understand though why MS is not releasing .dmp files for users. Due to privacy concerns. (Although those .dmps are still offloaded from a user's machine to MS servers, hah?) So, Stefan, just a thought, why not let us know the address of the exception and the exception code like it was before (see my post below) -- that would help a lot!

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** I want to point out that the following does not seem to work in the updated Windows Store anymore. Now if one goes to App -> Analytics -> Health a crash may look as such:

[image]

*and then Microsoft provides this little tidbit:*

[image]

*Neither of those gave me any useful information to locate the crash, as it was before (see below.) And I obviously do not want to ship my app with a `.pdb` file, or symbols, like it is suggested above.*

*So if anyone finds a working solution, I'd be interested to know it...*

---

You know, I should probably give credit to Microsoft for actually implementing a stack trace collection from the UWP app crashes. I got my hands on the actual crash in my Windows Store Win32/UWP app and here's how I was able to utilize it to find a latent bug.

First, when you log in to your [dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows), check the app listing and see if there are any crashes:

[image]

If so, click on that number/link and scroll all the way down to where it details the `Failures`. In my case it was a crash that looked like this:

[image]

Click it, that will bring up another window. Scroll down to `Failure Log`:

[image]

It will show you when the crash took place, the version of your app, what device it occurred in (which is very nice!) and then have a link for the stack trace. So click it:

[image]

That is how my actual stack trace looked like at the moment of the crash. Since that person's computer did not have symbols (`.pdb` file) with my executable, all methods in my app show as blank offsets.

**Here's how to find the actual location of the crash:**

Restore your Visual Studio solution with the exact copy of the crashed files. (I'm assuming that you archived the `release` build of your solution along with `.exe` and `.pdb` files before uploading it to the Windows Store.)

Start Visual Studio, open the version of the crashed app, switch to `Release` 
configuration and [disable builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106060/843732). (This part is important, because otherwise Visual Studio will try to build your project before you begin debugging it, which may mess up your function offsets that you got from the stack trace!)

Then place a breakpoint somewhere in one of the first constructors that will load up immediately with your app. You need to make sure that it triggers before the crash.

Start debugging (hit `F5`) and wait for the breakpoint to hit. Then display `Modules` pane (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`U`) and locate your executable and get its base address:

[image]

In my case it was `0xD0000`. Then switch to disassembly (`Alt`+`8`) and type in your base address + crash offset from the stack trace above in the `Address` bar on top of the disassembly window. It my case it was:

```
0xD0000+0x1D500
```

[image]

and hit `Enter` to display the location in the code. This will show you where the crash took place. In my case it was this line:

[image]

Then it all depends on your debugging skills. In my case it was pretty easy to see -- the `nRow` index was out of bounds. So it was pretty trivial to fix this bug.

Again, I want to express gratitude to Microsoft for providing such a feature. I was not aware of the bug that I showed above and I would be hard-pressed if I was trying to discover what crashes an application after just a plain end-user report.

PS. Lastly, I think the reason my stack trace was not collected in my first example was because the app was hung. So in that case the debugging information is probably not collected. (Just a guess at this point.)

Comment: This is great method. I have base address 00B50000 - how it convert to hex format?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this method to create a dump file.

1. While you are debugging a process in Visual Studio, you can save a dump file when the debugger has stopped at an exception or at a breakpoint. Choose **Save Dump As, Debug**. In the **Save Dump As** dialog box, in the **Save as type list**, you can select **Minidump** or **Minidump with Heap** (the default).
2. With [Just-In-Time Debugging enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio), you can attach the debugger to a crashed process that is running outside the debugger, and then save a dump file. See [Attach to Running Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger).
3. Other method to [create dump file](http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/docs/html/using_minidump.html).
   More detail info, you can refer to [using Dump files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files).

Hope this may be helpful to you.

Comment: @CheeryBu: Well, if I had debugger running on that machine I wouldn't need to save a dump file. I'm asking about a situation when my app crashes on an end-user's machine. Does Windows Store collect crash dumps from UWP apps that I can retrieve in that case?

Comment: @c00000fd, I think that you may not get dumps file from Windows Dev Center dashboard directly, if you need it , please report your [feedback](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n) to Microsoft. Thanks.