# Getting Symbols from crashes at Microsoft Dev Dashboard

Tags: windbg, crash-reports, minidump, windows-dev-center, postmortem-debugging

The Microsoft Windows Dev Center Dashboard lets me collect stack traces from failures in my native desktop app in the wild.

Unfortunately, minidumps aren't avaialble. I just get a TSV file that (sometimes) has a stack trace in it, which looks like this:

```
Frame   Image   Function    Offset
0   MyApp       0x2F59A1    
1   MyApp       0x11CEA8    
2   MyApp       0x11AE74    
3   MyApp       0x151289    
4   MyApp       0x2A686 
5   MyApp       0x180720    
6   MyApp       0x1807B6    
7   MyApp       0x2E875A    
8   MyApp       0x2E8882    
9   kernel32    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x24    
10  ntdll   __RtlUserThreadStart    0x2B    
11  ntdll   _RtlUserThreadStart 0x1B
```

To make this uesful, I load the matching binary in WinDbg, figure out the offset plus the base address, and unassemble at the resulting address. If my app loads at 0x00400000, I add 0x2F59A1 to it and get 0x006F59A1. Unassembling there shows me the return address of that stack frame, so I can get some idea of what the crash is about.

Is there a better way? How can I request minidumps from Dev Center? (Microsoft Support says I just can't. Really?) Is there a script to convert at TSV file a usable stack trace so I don't manually evaluate each stack frame? Is there some other way?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527577/how-to-get-a-crash-dump-or-any-usable-crash-report-for-a-converted-windows-sto

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasWeller, I'll see if I can get my suppor contact to confirm the availability of dumps. I sometimes get these TSV call stacks without a dump, and I wish that they were more readily usable. I've got a couple dozen TSV files and only one downloadable minidump file (as of this moment).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get a .dmp or not google says you can not get one from dash board

the answer below is a modified version of a script 
I once used it to disassemble  @ .map file offsets  improvise if needed 
it takes the offsets from the column using pandas
creates a command string and uses subprocess to disassemble at that offset

i assume the tsv is a tab seperated value file  if not you have some tweaking to do

assuming tab seperated file with data like below

```
Frame   Image   Function    Offset
0   calc    0x1012
0   calc    0x1015
```

you can automate the process  with some for loops in the code below

edit since i do two subprocess calls the offsets for both forward and backward disassembly are different (ASLR effect )

```
:\>cat Untitled.py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("tsv.txt" , delimiter='\t')
print df
offset = df.Function.unique()[1]
print offset
import subprocess
cmdline = "cdb -c \"ub calc+"+offset+";q\" calc.exe | tail"
print cmdline
output = subprocess.check_output(cmdline ,shell=True )
print output
cmdline = "cdb -c \"u calc+"+offset+";q\" calc.exe | tail"
print cmdline
output = subprocess.check_output(cmdline ,shell=True )
print output
:\>python Untitled.py
   Frame Image Function  Offset
0      0  calc   0x1012     NaN
1      0  calc   0x1015     NaN
0x1015
cdb -c "ub calc+0x1015;q" calc.exe | tail
calc!_imp__SHGetFolderPathW+0x1:
00f31005 57              push    edi
00f31006 1f              pop     ds
00f31007 7629            jbe     calc!_imp__GdipCloneImage+0x2 (00f31032)
00f31009 a1237683dd      mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[DD837623h]
00f3100e 27              daa
00f3100f 7646            jbe     calc!_imp__GdipDeleteGraphics+0x3 (00f31057)
00f31011 1e              push    ds
00f31012 197600          sbb     dword ptr [esi],esi
quit:

cdb -c "u calc+0x1015;q" calc.exe | tail
calc!⌂SHELL32_NULL_THUNK_DATA+0x1:
009b1015 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
009b1017 007a41          add     byte ptr [edx+41h],bh
009b101a 5f              pop     edi
009b101b 7700            ja      calc!⌂SHLWAPI_NULL_THUNK_DATA+0x1 (009b101d)
009b101d 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al
009b101f 005fa1          add     byte ptr [edi-5Fh],bl
009b1022 687449a568      push    68A54974h
009b1027 744a            je      calc!_imp__GdiplusShutdown+0x3 (009b1073)
quit:


:\>
```