# Qt software debugging techniques

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have the application which is published to the `Microsoft Store`, under health page for the application in the `Dev center`, it reports crash issue:

`fail_fast_fatal_app_exit_c0000409_qt5core.dll!qt_logging_to_console`

**And stack trace:**

```
0   ucrtbase.dll    abort   0x000000000000004E
1   Qt5Core.dll qt_logging_to_console   0x000000000000017A
2   Qt5Core.dll QMessageLogger::fatal   0x0000000000000093
3   Qt5Gui.dll  QPixmap::paintEngine    0x0000000000000052
4   Qt5Gui.dll  QPixmap::QPixmap    0x0000000000000037
```

When debugging the application I don't get any crashes. The question is how to get the crash location or function line/name in the code by the stack trace? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: 1) build your code with debug symbols. 2) make sure you have said debug symbols available.

Comment: @JesperJuhl
Hi! What do you mean by option 2? I have the project .pdb file.

Comment: The stack trace points to Qt functions only. Is it complete? Where are your code functions?

Comment: @vahancho
Hi! It doesn't show any of my code functions. If I knew the functions names, then no point to create the topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was with programs icons creation/destruction on the fly and `DestroyIcon` destroyed the handle which was in use.

I added some improvements, now it only creates 1 object of `HICON` and `QPixmap`, then appends to the structure in the loop and after the loop exited it calls `DestroyIcon` function to destroy the `HICON` handle.

Also I have found this article about finding bugs from the Microsoft Store:
[How to get a crash dump (or any usable crash report) for a converted Windows Store UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527577/how-to-get-a-crash-dump-or-any-usable-crash-report-for-a-converted-windows-sto)

But also I'm going to try `StackWalker` application to check for other issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The hexes look like some offsets, maybe from function start as they are small. You could download and compile [dia2dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/dia2dump-sample?view=vs-2017) utility (it is also somewhere in VS samples), which can dump lots of information about debugging symbols, including line numbers for each offset. So you would know the line numbers for the stack.

PS note you need to have the Qt's pdbs, not your program ones, to investigate this stack.